# Sum of many binomially distributed random variables

Tags: probability

A pair of fair die are rolled $1200$ times and I wish to find the probability of the die displaying a different number in less than $985$ out of the $1200$ rolls. I though I would just write:
$$P=\sum_{i=0}^{984}P\left(X=i\right)$$
Where $X\sim Bin(1200,5/6)$, but how can I calculate this monstrous thing? Even taking the complementary event will require a lot of calculations. What is an easier way of calculating that? I'm sure I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: I asswume that "displaying a different number" means  "throwing non-doubles"?  Thus $(1,5)$, say, as opposed to $(4,4)$. If so, just use the normal approximation to the binomial.

Comment: Assuming that the comment of @lulu is appropriate, then I advise googling for : "normal approximation to binomial".

Comment: Thanks both of you!